# RESTful using the same endpoint with id or other parameter is a good practice?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, api-design, restful-url

**Scenario**

I have a case when I want get something by id, common case, and some times by date.

Eg.:

```
/companies/:id/tickets/:id
/companies/:id/tickets/:date
```

From my studies this is not a good practice but and here come my doubt about it.

Should I use the endpoint without the **id** and use the payload to get the date?

Eg.:

```
/companies/:id/tickets
```

This should return all tickets from that company right? So getting some date data from the payload and use that as a filter the return don't seems right to me. My endpoints would not be honest about what they are doing if I do that.

What RESTful practice I should use here?

Comment: You should use query params for filtering: /companies/:id/tickets?date=2011-11-11T11:11:11Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/companies/:id/tickets/:id` - this is fine for getting a single resource.

I think most people would agree filtering and searching resources would be best done with query parameters. In fact, the JSONAPI spec has a recommendation regarding it specifically.

Read up on http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#filtering and the other recommendations, they cover the most common use cases such as yours.

You can also have a standalone `tickets` resource and implement the company id filter for it as well as, in general, having multiple URLs for the same resource(s) is perfectly fine.